# how to load https image in com.daimajia.slider:library

Tags: android

```
DefaultSliderView  textSliderView;//class level decleratrion 

SliderLayout sliderShow;//class level decleratrion

sliderShow = (SliderLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.slider);//initialization at on create

textSliderView.image(baseurl+respo.getJSONObject(i).getString("bannerimageurl"));
sliderShow.addSlider(textSliderView);
```

Comment: Must be the problem of Picasso configuration. Do  you get any error logs?

Comment: No i am not getting any crashes Picasso library will load a error image if fetching image is a problem

Comment: if possible suggest an alternative

Comment: Try updating picasso to the latest, follow this link - https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/500